# Easy way to get formated number from a text file?

Tags: java, string, text, numbers

so I know in C++ I can just do this:

```
ifstream file("data/maps/ssdebug1.cfg");
    string line;
float startx = 0;
    sscanf (line.c_str(), "start-x = %f;", &startx);
```

But is there a equally easy way to do this in Java?

Comment: NumberFormat package http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can do

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/maps/ssdebug1.cfg");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(fis);
fis.close();

// you can have any number of properties with comments. 
// However, it is not assumed aline ends with a ';'
String start_x = prop.getProperty("start-x");
double startx = Double.parseDouble(start_x);
```

Answer (score 1):

from java Version 1.5 you can use java.util.Scanner also..
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Example :

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data/maps/ssdebug1.cfg"));
      while (in.hasNextLong()) {
          long my = in.nextLong();
      }
```